# dynamically generating html, quotes and forward slashes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is driving me nuts; I am dynamically creating a string in jquery like this:

```
html += "<div class='myClass' " + "onClick=ajaxReq('GET', '/ws/trophies/" + genID +         
        "')>";
```

In chrome dev tools I see this generated instead:

```
<div class="myClass" onclick="ajaxReq('GET'," ' ws trophies 3')>
```

Answer (score 0):

would this work instead?

```
$(document).on('click','.myClass',function () {
  ajaxReq('GET', "/ws/trophies/" + $(this).attr("id")); // or something     

});
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.google.com/#q=onclick+is+bad

```
html += "<div class='myClass'>";

$(document).on('click', '.myClass', function() {
    ajaxReq('GET', '/ws/trophies/' + genID);
});
```

Comment: the problem with that is accessing genId since it's out of scope?  I would have to use genId as part of an attribute to the selector that is registered with the click event.

Comment: I would probably do just what you said: create data-genid attribute on .myClass div, and then access it like this: $(this).attr("data-genid")